# Getting all but the first k rows from a group in a GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas `GroupBy` object. I am using `head(k)` to extract the first k elements of each group into a dataframe and I want to also extract the complement. Each group has a nonconstant size.

Is there any straightforwards way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d','d'],
             'Data':np.arange(10)})

   Data ID
0     0  a
1     1  b
2     2  b
3     3  c
4     4  c
5     5  c
6     6  d
7     7  d
8     8  d
9     9  d

df[~df.index.isin(df.groupby('ID').head(2).index)]
```

Output:

```
   Data ID
5     5  c
8     8  d
9     9  d
```

Where `df.groupby('ID').head(2)` returns:

```
   Data ID
0     0  a
1     1  b
2     2  b
3     3  c
4     4  c
6     6  d
7     7  d
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesy, You can use reindex the new dataframe using the reset_index() method.